# vmc apps capturing output

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc

I need to capture the output of the `vmc apps` or `vmc apps --full` command so that the captured information can be analyzed and be used in our system.

If we execute the command we get something like this:

```
foo                 stopped   1 x 512M   java7     none                              
peter               stopped   1 x 512M   java7     none
```

This is what we need since it contains all kinds of useful information; status, instance count etc.

The problem is that as soon as we start to redirect the output (the error stream remains empty), that the only thing we get is:

```
foo
peter
```

So some very important information somehow is lost.

Although we can see the relevant information in the console, we are not able to capture the information. Can someone explain what is going on and perhaps provide a solution to our conundrum?

Peter Veentjer
Cloudsoft

Answer (score 1):

Would you not be better off using one of the APIs available to query the Cloud Foundry instance?